# Pentaho's Kettle Server OutOfMemory Error

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle

I'm a newbie in using Pentaho. In my local env, I use Pentaho's Spoon to develop ETL and on my server we use kettle as Pentaho Server. I often ran into OutOfMemory error both in my local env and on my server.

On kettle server, we have 4GB of memory. Our server run import daily, the data we import is about > 100k records in 10 seperate imports. We have figure out that, when a import is finished, the memory which that import has used is still being kept inside the memory without release.

I have a work-around that each time we try to import, we restart the Kettle server and restart Spoon in my local env. In the image below, is the analyze about the memory.

[image]

Comment: do you execute all 10 imports at same time?'

Comment: No, in sequence.

Comment: how do you execute jobs? using kitchen utility or via spoon interface only?

Comment: Via a Spoon interface in my local and via rest with Kettle server

Comment: execute jobs using kitchen utility your issue will resolve,

Comment: Follow my understanding, kitchen is command line tool to trigger job. What is the different between trigger via Rest (Kettle) and trigger via command line(Kitchen)? Do you have a document about this? I need something to show to my team, in order to change from using Kettle to Kitchen...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225451/discussion-between-nguyn-dc-tam-and-helping-hand).